# Select from a relative with foreign key?

Tags: mysql, select, foreign-keys

I have these tables:

```
create table CLIENTE (
idCliente int primary key auto_increment,
name varchar(255)


create table ANIMAL (
idAnimal int primary key,
name varchar(255),
foreign key (idCliente) references CLIENTE (idClinete) on delete set null on update cascade
```

How do I list (with Select * from methood) the names of the animals from the client John? 
It's sort of an executable so I know that it wouldn't actually show the names if I runned the code, but aside that how can I just make the code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have an `idCliente` column in the `ANIMAL` table:

```
create table ANIMAL (
    idAnimal INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255),
    idCliente INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (idCliente) REFERENCES CLIENTE (idCliente) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Then you use it in a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM ANIMAL AS a
JOIN CLIENTE AS c ON a.idCliente = c.idCliente
WHERE c.name = 'John';
```